# How can one say pressure is constant in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

When a gas expands by  b charles law pressure increases
$$\frac{p}{t}=k$$
thermodynamics says:
$$dQ=dU+PdV$$
so herfe one is considering constant pressure but how b charles law says it changes?So shouldn't it be:
$$dQ=dU+PdV+VdP$$
can't we apply a variable external pressure?

Comment: The volume work done by the system is dW=p.dV, not p.dV + Vdp. You may confuse it with H=U+pV -> dH=dU + d(pV) = dU + p.dV + V.dp.

Comment: Charles law is at constant volume,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in thermodynamics we wish to constrain pressure to be constant.  [Or we may wish to do a thermodynamic analysis for a system that is at constant pressure, which is a common laboratory condition.]   However, that is a choice.  Pressure is not generally constrained to be constant in thermodynamics.

For a closed system:

$$d\text{U} = \text{đ}q + \text{đ}w$$

[Note that I'm using a different sign convention from you for work, but the results come out the same.]

If the only type of work is $pV$- work, then  $\text{đ}w = -p_{ext}dV$, where $p_{ext}$ is the external pressure applied to the system by the surroundings.  Thus we have:

$$d\text{U} = \text{đ}q - p_{ext}dV,$$

where the pressure can change in any way you please during the process.

If the process is reversible, then (in that idealized case) the system is in continous equilibrium with its surroundings. As as a consequence, $p_{sys} =p* = p_{ext}$, and we can write:

$$d\text{U} = \text{đ}q - pdV$$

[*The convention is that if a subscript is not present, the variable is assumed to apply to the system.]

Comment: Ok so if pressure changes that means work is done and the basic violation of an assumtion m that there isno exteenal work.

Comment: No, a change in pressure does not necessarily mean work is done.  For instance, if you heat up a gas at constant volume, the pressure will increase, but no pV-work is done, because dV = 0.

Comment: So if both pressure and volume change that means external work is done?

Comment: Not quite.  If the volume changes, and the pressure is non-zero, then work is done, *regardless of whether the pressure changes or not*.  Thus the better statement is "If the pressure is non-zero, and the volume changes, then work is done."  It's helpful to understand the physics underlying work:  Work is a force exerted over a distance.  So in order to have work, you need force (≡ pressure) to be non-zero, and distance = change in position ≡ change in volume to be non-zero.

Comment: I am not talking about work done by the system but when work is being done on the system then.

Comment: What I wrote applies regardless of whether work is being done by the system (expansion) or on the system (compression). The only difference between the two is the sign.  Note also that the work and heat flows for a process are always defined by what changed *in the surroundings*.  Thus the p you use in calculating work is always the external pressure, regardless of whether the work is done by the system or on the system.  I think if you have more questions about work you might want to search chem.se (this site) and physics.se, and then, if you're still unclear, pose a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

[Charle's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles%27s_law) has nothing to do with the first law of thermodynamics, it simply states that for a gas, at constant pressure, volume will be directly proportional to temperature. Whereas, the first law of thermodynamics states that $\text{d}U=\text{d}Q+\text{d}W$, where $W$ is the work done on the system, which is equal to $-P\text{d}V$.

Now, it directly comes from the definition of work done, which is $\text{d}W=\vec{F} \cdot \text{d}\vec{x}$ and so if external pressure applied is $P$ over the cross sectional area $A$, we will have $F=PA$ and so $\text{d}W=-PA \text{d}x=-P\text{d}V$. The negative sign is taken as the direction of displacement and force applied by atmosphere is in opposite direction, so to make it positive, negative sign  is multiplied.

Comment: How can you say it is a constant "Force"?